# How to adjust position of a component that has been vertically and horizontally centered with `alignItems` and `justifyContent`?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

My goal is to adjust the `Icon` component to point to the exact coordinate. The current solution does centered the `Icon` component vertically and horizontally. But it's not precise enough compared to the `Marker` component.

The current solution is to add style to the Icon component with `top=-20` but I believe this is not the right solution. I believe `top=-20` is specific to my device alone, different device will result to different result.

I've tried to use the `Marker` component but I have not figured out how to prevent re-rendering each time there is a state update. note: without re-rendering the marker won't change position.

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import MapView, {Marker, PROVIDER_GOOGLE} from 'react-native-maps';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});

export default function GoSendDestinationDetails() {
  let coordinate = {
    latitude: -6.1754,
    longitude: 106.8272,
    latitudeDelta: 0.015,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
  };

  const handleRegionChange = (region) => {
    // console.log(region);
    coordinate = region;
  };

  // console.log('re-render');

  return (
    <View style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>
      <View style={[styles.container, {height: '50%', width: '100%'}]}>
        <MapView
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} // remove if not using Google Maps
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={coordinate}
          onRegionChange={handleRegionChange}>
          <Marker coordinate={coordinate} />
        </MapView>
        {/* TODO: use gojek assets */}
        <Icon name="map-marker-alt" size={36} color="orange" />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Icon inside a marker with your needed coordinates:

```
<Marker coordinate={coordinate}>
  <Icon name="map-marker-alt" size={36} color="orange" />
</Marker>
```

This will keep the icon in your needed position.

Comment: My goal is to put a vertically and horizontally centered `component` inside the `MapView`. The method I know to change the Marker coordinate require `re-render` which in my case will cause unnecessary re-render. There is a significant lag when used in an Android app with 512 MB. Do you know better way to change the Marker coordinate without re-rendering?

Comment: it's not possible to change something on the view without rerendering at all. You could optimise the rendering to improve performance. Which part of the rendering is to slow?